# What are the stages of child speech and language development?

Tags: language-development, speech

What are the distinct stages or landmarks or milestones in speech in language development, in the order they're *typically* reached, and why is it that order?

For instance, I know that certain types of phonemes are learned at different times. Vowels are usually learned early, and different types of consonants are learned later.

As well as phonetic mastery, there is also grammatical mastery. An example is expressed in: [I am vs my is - when do children develop this bit of language?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/11559/i-am-vs-my-is-when-do-children-develop-this-bit-of-language)

I'm asking primarily about English pronunciation and grammar.

Please feel comfortable using technical terms, such as those found in [Articulatory Phonetics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Articulatory_phonetics), [Occlusives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occlusive), [Manners of Articulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manner_of_articulation) and linguistic/grammatical terminology. I have access to resources about these areas of interest.

I'm particularly interested in the *why* of these developmental stages. Phoneme acquisition charts are easily found, but they don't discuss why certain phonemes are learned before others. A list of sounds/grammar rules and comparative ages isn't as useful to me as understanding the physiological or cognitive underpinnings of those milestones.

Age range can be assumed to be from start of speech until "mastery" of all landmarks. I'm not just interested in a single age, but the full breadth of development. (Unfortunately, I have to be this broad. Since I don't *know* the individual stages, I can't right now ask about them individually).

If necessary, I can separate phonemes from grammar for two separate questions.

Comment: This isn't a complete answer by far, but it has to do with physiological (neurological) development of control of the shape of the oral cavity (including pharynx), control of the tongue and lips, sound and speech recognition ability, presence or absence of teeth, etc. In other words, it's predictable because it's physiological. You might get an excellent answer on Linguistics.se.

Comment: That's my understanding, too, as far as muscle control, teeth, and other physiological developments go. But I haven't yet seen a concrete list such physical developmental stages and their respective phonetic acquisitions. I may just be looking in the wrong place. I do have a book on linguistics that scratches the surface, and it's what piqued my curiosity. I didn't think about the linguistics stack! Good advice.

Comment: If you don't get an answer there, let me know, and I'll search the physiological/neuro side for an answer. But this is part of their bread and butter, I think.

Comment: Might be an interesting question to ask on ELU stack exchange.

Comment: I finally had time to modify this question to ask on Linguistics: http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/11991/what-are-the-stages-of-child-speech-and-language-development

Answer (score 3):

Age of Child (source: http://childdevelopmentinfo.com/child-development/language_development/)

6 Months

Vocalization with intonation
Responds to his name
Responds to human voices without visual cues by turning his head and eyes
Responds appropriately to friendly and angry tones

12 Months

Uses one or more words with meaning (this may be a fragment of a word)
Understands simple instructions, especially if vocal or physical cues are given
Practices inflection
Is aware of the social value of speech
18 Months
Has vocabulary of approximately 5-20 words
Vocabulary made up chiefly of nouns
Some echolalia (repeating a word or phrase over and over)
Much jargon with emotional content
Is able to follow simple commands

24 Months

Can name a number of objects common to his surroundings
Is able to use at least two prepositions, usually chosen from the following: in, on, under
Combines words into a short sentence-largely noun-verb combinations (mean) length of sentences is given as 1.2 words
Approximately 2/3 of what child says should be intelligible
Vocabulary of approximately 150-300 words
Rhythm and fluency often poor
Volume and pitch of voice not yet well-controlled
Can use two pronouns correctly: I, me, you, although me and I are often confused
My and mine are beginning to emerge
Responds to such commands as “show me your eyes (nose, mouth, hair)”

36 Months

Use pronouns I, you, me correctly
Is using some plurals and past tenses
Knows at least three prepositions, usually in, on, under
Knows chief parts of body and should be able to indicate these if not name
Handles three word sentences easily
Has in the neighborhood of 900-1000 words
About 90% of what child says should be intelligible
Verbs begin to predominate
Understands most simple questions dealing with his environment and activities
Relates his experiences so that they can be followed with reason
Able to reason out such questions as “what must you do when you are sleepy, hungry, cool, or thirsty?”
Should be able to give his sex, name, age
Should not be expected to answer all questions even though he understands what is expected

48 Months

Knows names of familiar animals
Can use at least four prepositions or can demonstrate his understanding of their meaning when given commands
Names common objects in picture books or magazines
Knows one or more colors
Can repeat 4 digits when they are given slowly
Can usually repeat words of four syllables
Demonstrates understanding of over and under
Has most vowels and diphthongs and the consonants p, b, m, w, n well established
Often indulges in make-believe
Extensive verbalization as he carries out activities
Understands such concepts as longer, larger, when a contrast is presented
Readily follows simple commands even thought the stimulus objects are not in sight
Much repetition of words, phrases, syllables, and even sounds

60 Months

Can use many descriptive words spontaneously-both adjectives and adverbs
Knows common opposites: big-little, hard-soft, heave-light, etc
Has number concepts of 4 or more
Can count to ten
Speech should be completely intelligible, in spite of articulation problems
Should have all vowels and the consonants, m,p,b,h,w,k,g,t,d,n,ng,y (yellow)
Should be able to repeat sentences as long as nine words
Should be able to define common objects in terms of use (hat, shoe, chair)
Should be able to follow three commands given without interruptions
Should know his age
Should have simple time concepts: morning, afternoon, night, day, later, after, while
Tomorrow, yesterday, today
Should be using fairly long sentences and should use some compound and some complex sentences
Speech on the whole should be grammatically correct

6 Years

In addition to the above consonants these should be mastered: f, v, sh, zh, th,1
He should have concepts of 7
Speech should be completely intelligible and socially useful
Should be able to tell one a rather connected story about a picture, seeing relationships
Between objects and happenings

7 Years

Should have mastered the consonants s-z, r, voiceless th, ch, wh, and the soft g as in George
Should handle opposite analogies easily: girl-boy, man-woman, flies-swims, blunt-sharp short-long, sweet-sour, etc
Understands such terms as: alike, different, beginning, end, etc
Should be able to tell time to quarter hour
Should be able to do simple reading and to write or print many words

8 Years

Can relate rather involved accounts of events, many of which occurred at some time in the past
Complex and compound sentences should be used easily
Should be few lapses in grammatical constrictions-tense, pronouns, plurals
All speech sounds, including consonant blends should be established
Should be reading with considerable ease and now writing simple compositions
Social amenities should be present in his speech in appropriate situations
Control of rate, pitch, and volume are generally well and appropriately established
Can carry on conversation at rather adult level
Follows fairly complex directions with little repetition
Has well developed time and number concepts

Comment: Can you include a link to the site that provided this information? It's always nice to cite your sources :)

Comment: Sure, added. It's http://childdevelopmentinfo.com/child-development/language_development/